# Unable to use javascript/jquery function in php?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I made a jQuery for removing and adding css for a input field. To make it become a switch.

Normally, this field not be show out. That field will be displayed when I pressed a button, and the button will be remove.

And I tested this function in html which is work! But when I change the html file to be php file, this function become unworkable.

Here is my code:

html:

```
<div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
   <label class="text_label">Password:</label>
   <div class="form-row" id="swapping">
      <div class="form-group">
        <button type="button" name="" class="btn btn-primary form-control" onclick="swap();">Change Password</button>
      </div>
   </div>
    <div class="form-row change_password" id="password_field">
      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="password" name="" class="form-control" value="">
      </div>
    </div>
 </div>
```

css:

```
.change_password
{
  display: none;
}
```

javascript/jquery:

```
function swap()
{
  $('#swapping').remove();

  $('#password_field').removeClass('change_password');
}
```

Doesn't know why the function can be work in html but not working in php. (add the input field into the page and remove the button after pressed it). However, there is no error exist.

---

Problem Solved, another question comes out

When I code the js function in a js file then link to the php page that the function will be undefined.

But if I code the function in the php page which will defined and working. This situation will not happen in html, why it only happen in php?

Comment: What do you mean when you say it doesn't work? Is there some error? Is you webserver capable of handling php files?

Comment: only this function is not working, because I have other php code(different functions) in the same page which are working fine.

Comment: PHP can't affect Javascript. If it works as HTML then it will work as PHP. I think you need to provide more details about "doesn't work"

Comment: I added the 'doesn't work' detail, hope you can take a look on that.

Comment: Are you using chrome? Did you check the inspector console for errors and/or event listeners on your element?

Comment: I checked the inspector console just now, that told me swap is not defined. But you can see I have defined it above...

Comment: The developer console doesn't lie.